# Crystal Reports .Net Invalid File Name Error

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

We're running into a very strange problem on one of our reporting servers (running Crystal Reports for .Net 4 in IIS on a Windows 2008 server). When trying to run a report, we get an error saying "Load Report Failed", with an InnerException of "Invalid file name". This just started a few months ago, and had been working fine for years previously.

I have checked online and all the suggestions that I can find have been tried to no avail. A few notes about this issue:

- Everything I can find on the Internet indicates this is a problem generating the temp report file. We have changed the registry setting TemDir to point to a different location than the standard temp directory.
- We can see that the temporary .rpt files **are** being created in the desired directory, even when we get the error. I pulled one down locally and it opens in Crystal Reports designer with the data I would have expected.
- We are not trying to export the reports to any file format, we are just using the standard report renderer.
- This is only happening in one environment. When we copied the code that works in our higher environment Crystal server, we still get the same error.
- Our server management team assures us no server changes have happened just prior to the issue (though I'm not sure we can prove that definitively).

Some fixes I have tried (not necessarily in this order):

- Giving the account that the Website uses read/write access to the root of C:
- Adding the account that the Website uses to the Administrators local group
- Removing, then re-adding read/write/execute permissions to the temporary report directory. (Same results as above - temp files are created but we get the error still.)
- Giving the account that the Website uses access to C:\Windows\Temp (no reason why that should matter since we are specifying the temp directory but thought I would give it a whirl anyway)
- Stopped/started IIS, the application pool, rebooted the server.

Does anyone have any other suggestions we can look at for this problem? My gut tells me that there's still some lingering permissions issue but I can't find it.

As requested, here is some code where the error occurs:

```
 Private Sub OpenReportFile()
    Dim reportPath As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportFileLocation")
    If _reportDefinition Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    _theReport = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    _theReport.Load(reportPath & _reportDefinition.ReportFilePath, OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
End Sub
```

The error is thrown on _theReport.Load.

AppSettings("ReportFileLocation") contains the base folder (a local path on the D drive) where the .rpt files reside.

_reportDefinition is a local domain object that contains the specific report path.

When the two are combined, the value of reportPath would be a local path like "D:\Inet\docroot\WebCrystal\Reports\MyReportFile.rpt"

This issue happens for every report.

Comment: Do you have some code?  Can you post the filename that is giving you the issues?

Comment: @Paddy - added some details to the main post. Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing crystal reports?